# Could use some tips on a Functional Analysis Problem

Tags: functional-analysis

could use some help answering a question:

Let $A \in \mathscr{B}\left(\ell^{1}\right)$ be defined by $(A f)(m)=\sum_{n}\left(2^{-m}\left(1-2^{-n}\right) f(n)\right)$. Prove that $A\left(\right.$ ball $\left.\ell^{1}\right)$ is not closed.

---

Let $\tau \in \ell^{1}$ be defined by $\tau(n)=2^{-n} .$ Then  --***this is where I'm stuck***--  $\tau \in$ $\left(\operatorname{cl} A\left(\right.\right.$ ball $\left.\left.\ell^{1}\right)\right) \backslash A\left(\right.$ ball $\left.\ell^{1}\right) .$ Thus $A\left(\right.$ ball $\left.\ell^{1}\right)$ is not closed.

Comment: That was straight from the prof's question. And he did write (Af)(m).

Comment: Your $\tau$ does not work. It is the image of $f$ defined by $f(n)=\frac1 {2^{n}-1}$.

Comment: That was straight from his hints. In my attempt, I noted $|| \tau ||=1$ and then massaged the series: 

$ (A \tau)(m) = \sum_{n}\left(2^{-m}\left(1-2^{-n}\right) \tau(n)\right) = $

$\sum_{n} \left(2^{-m}\left(2^{-n}-2^{-2n}\right)\right) =$ 

$ 2^{-m}(1-\frac{1}{3}) = 2^{-m+1}\frac{1}{3} $... But... this got me nowhere... in the end he told me my attempt was, "very wrong"

Comment: So $\mathscr B(\ell^1)$ means the space of bounded (continuous) linear maps $\ell^1\to\ell^1$? So if $f\in\ell^1$, then $Af\in\ell^1$ and the notation makes sense.

Comment: @TedShifrin yes. $\mathscr{B(l^{1})}$ is the space of bounded linear maps, $\mathscr{l^{1}} \to \mathscr{l^{1}}$

Comment: Last question: Do sequences start with $m=0$ or $m=1$?

Comment: Just to be clear, $A f \in \operatorname{sp}\{ m \mapsto {1 \over 2^m} \}$, correct? And are you talking about the open ball in $l^1$?

Comment: @TedShifrin He didn't say, I assumed the index started at 1. My argument being $n^{-2}$ is $l^{2}$

Comment: @copper.hat I'm not clear on your notation.

Comment: The range of $A$ is one dimensional?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

As [Kavi Rama Murthy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/142385/kavi-rama-murthy) points out in a comment, $\ \tau=A(f)\ $, where
$\ f(n)=\frac{1}{2^n-1}\ $. But $\ \|f\|_1=$$\,1+\sum_\limits{i=2}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n-1}>1\ $, so this shows that $\ \tau\not\in A\big(\,\text{ball}\,\ell^1\big)\ $.

Now let $\ \delta(g)=\tau-A(g)\ $, then
$$
\|\delta(g)\|_1=\Big|1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1-2^{-n})g(n)\,\Big|\ .
$$
What happens if you take
$$
g(n)=\cases{0&for $\ n\le N$\\
            2^{N-n}&for $\ n>N$}\ \ ?
$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that $Af = \phi(f) \cdot \tau$, where $\phi:l_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ is
$\phi(f) = \sum_k (1-{1 \over 2^k}) f_k$. Let $B$ be the unit ball in $l_1$. We see that $I=\phi(B)$ is a bounded interval ($B$ is convex and $\phi$ is linear & bounded).

Suppose $I$ is closed. Then there is some unit norm $f$ with such that $\phi(f) = \max I$. Note that we can take $f_k \ge 0$ for all $k$ since $\phi(|f|) \ge \phi(f)$ (where $|f|_k = |f_k|$).

Let $R$ be the right shift and
note that $\|Rf\|=\|f\|$. Note that $\phi(Rf) > \phi(f)$ since the sequence
$k \mapsto 1 - {1 \over 2^k}$ is strictly increasing, which contradicts $\phi(f) = \max I$. In particular, $I$ is not closed.

Then choose unit $f_k$ such that $\phi(f_k) \to \max I$ and we see that $Af_k \to \max I \cdot \tau$, but $\max I \cdot \tau \notin A(B)$.

(It is straightforward to check that $\|A\| = 1$, so we have $I=(-1,1)$.)